# Mistake retrieve value bit field in SQLserver table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-fields

I have a table with a field type: bit null able name is "AField".
when select in this table with id table return record "AField" is false whereas correct value is true:

`Select * FROM CustomerService WHERE CustomerServiceId = @CustomerServiceId`

When i select in table to getrecords with "AField" is true  in result that record is exist:

`Select * FROM CustomerService where AField =1`

Comment: Consider posting your query, otherwise there's no context with which to work.

Comment: @RamblinRose `Select *
 FROM CustomerService
      WHERE CustomerServiceId = @CustomerServiceId`

Comment: Sample data and the results you are getting would help.  I also note that your question is about `AField`, but that is not referenced at all in the query.  I'm confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  `Select *
 FROM CustomerService
 where AField =1`

Comment: You have now posted 2 different queries - which is confusing. In addition, you have made an assumption that contributes to the general confusion. A bit datatype is a numeric datatype, not boolean. It's value is either 0 or 1 (or null). There are various ways to interpret this as "TRUE" or "FALSE" but that is an interpretation of the actual value. So where do you do this interpretation? In application code? If so, post or examine your code - we can't because you did not include any code.